# Using .Net to Stagger Columns in an Excel Worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, .net-4.0

I am working on a small VB.Net app that will generate an Excel workbook based on several queries from a database. I have a query that returns a datatable containing a date (Outage_Date), ID (ID) and an issue type (Issue_Type). I am trying to place these in staggered columns based on the ID and the issue type, but I'm struggling to come up with the logic to do this.

The datatable looks like this:

```
Outage_Date  ID    Issue_Type  
1/1/2010     123   Start
2/5/2010     456   Start
3/17/2011    123   Minor
1/2/2012     123   Major
9/25/2012    456   Major
10/5/2012    456   Minor
```

The output should look like this:

```
Date         123     456
1/1/2010     Start   
2/5/2010             Start
3/17/2011    Minor
1/2/2012     Major
9/25/2012            Major
10/5/2012            Minor
```

How can I approach this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This method uses [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to query the `DataTable`, assumes [`Option Infer On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx), and is a mix of code and pseudocode!  I don't know what you are using to build the Excel spreadsheet, so I made that part up based on [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) syntax.  It's also untested, so let me know how it works out - hopefully it's enough to point you in the right direction, although there may be more elegant solutions!

```
' Build a list of the IDs
Dim ids = datatable.AsEnumberable() _
    .Select(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of Integer)("ID")) _
    .Distinct() _
    .OrderBy(Function(x) x) _
    .ToList()
' Headings
Dim row = 1, col = 1
worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = "Date"
For Each id In ids
    col += 1
    worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = CStr(id)
Next
' Data Values
For Each dr In datatable.Rows
    row += 1
    col = 1
    worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = dr.Field(Of Date)("Outage_Date")
    col += 1
    ' Work out how many columns to shift the issue type over
    Dim offset = ids.IndexOf(dr.Field(Of Integer)("ID"))
    col += offset
    worksheet.Cell(row, col).Value = dr.Field(Of String)("Issue_Type")
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm using [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate the spreadsheet. The syntax looks similar to what you have. I appreciate your work. Let me take a look at it and we'll see how it goes.